# Fix for "Illegal string offset"?

Tags: php, wordpress

My server error log is showing the following error:

```
[03-Feb-2016 09:04:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'results-page' in /home/myaccount/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-author-search/simple-author-search.php on line 35
```

This is a self-authored WordPress plugin which lets visitors search WordPress users on the front end. The affected code is as follows, line 35 in question is the one beginning "$form =".

```
function showForm($atts = array()) {
    $keywords = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'sas-keywords');
    $form = '<form action="' . get_permalink($atts['results-page']) . '"name="sas-form" class="sas-form form-inline pull-xs-right"><input type="hidden" name="sas-search" value="1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sas-keywords" value="' . htmlentities($keywords) . '"/>' . '&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-secondary" /></form>';
    return $form;
}
```

Could you please help me understand why the text results-page is causing this error?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `$atts` is not an array when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illegal string offset means, you want access an offset from an string with an illegal key. Because a string could never be an legal offset for an string, this ends in your warning.

In your case, you have to ensure, `$atts` is an array and the key `results-page` exists.

```
function showForm($atts = array()) {
    if (!is_array($atts) || !isset($atts['results-page'])) {
        // invalid argument - do some error handling
        return '';
    }

    $keywords = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'sas-keywords');
    $form = '<form action="' . get_permalink($atts['results-page']) . '"name="sas-form" class="sas-form form-inline pull-xs-right"><input type="hidden" name="sas-search" value="1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sas-keywords" value="' . htmlentities($keywords) . '"/>' . '&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-secondary" /></form>';
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Philipp - thanks very much. Afraid I'm not quite knowledgeable enough to fully understand the explanation - but the addition of these checks appears to eliminate the error. I'm checking whether $atts is an array and whether results-page exists, okay. Thanks.